# QMediaPlayer samples overlap despite using stop()

Tags: c++, qt, audio

In my resource files I have 31 samples of engine sounds. I would like to make a slider, which moving will change a sample for another one(going higher engine starts to yell, lower it is going calmer). My code from slider:

```
void MainWindow::on_poziomMocy_sliderMoved(int position)
{
    QMediaPlayer * music = new QMediaPlayer();
   //play umieścić w caseach i kończyć je stop. Tak jak to miałem wcześniej, dodać cały plik
    //do resources
    switch(position)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            music->stop();
            music->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/dźwięki/859.wav"));
            music->play();
        }
        case 1:
        {
            music->stop();
            music->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/dźwięki/919.wav"));
            music->play();
        }
        case 2:
        {
            music->stop();
            music->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/dźwięki/984.wav"));
            music->play();
        }
        case 3:
        {
            music->stop();
            music->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/dźwięki/1052.wav"));
            music->play();
        }
        case 4:
        {
            music->stop();
            music->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/dźwięki/1126.wav"));
            music->play();
        }
   }
```

When I play this and slide a slider samples are overlaping and my speakers are crying. I don't know what to do the "music" scope is right, why does stop() do not work properly?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of each time you slide a slider new `QMediaPlayer` created:

```
QMediaPlayer * music = new QMediaPlayer();
```

You should place player creation at some another place. For exaple at your class constructor.